# Should I resolve or reject when no action is taking place?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

In one of my applications I have a function which returns a `Promise()` and since this action requires updating an API, I am checking if the last function call asked to send the same information:

```
module.exports = function updateSidebar(sidebar) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (sidebar === lastSidebar) {
        // What to I do here?
    } else {
        // Application Logic
    }
  });
}
```

In this instance, would I `reject()` the `Promise()`, for giving me "invalid" data, or do I `resolve()` implying the action has been completed successfully? (which it has, just earlier)

Any advice is very welcome!

Comment: Resolving seems more appropriate. Reject implies something went wrong, which it didn't.

Comment: Don't know the syntax, or what's needed, but wouldn't it be simpler to just do a negative comparison, and run the application logic if the sidebar and lastSidebar doesn't match?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie - `updateSidebar()` is returning a promise and that's what the caller expects so it needs to still return the promise, even if there's nothing to do and, if that is considered a success scenario, then it needs to resolve that promise too so the `if/else` is perfectly appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the result you want, then just `resolve(result)`.  That works perfectly fine and unless you consider this an error (in which case you would reject), then you should just resolve with some successful result.

```
module.exports = function updateSidebar(sidebar) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (sidebar === lastSidebar) {
        resolve(someSuccessfulResult);
    } else {
        // Application Logic
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This makes sense! Thanks!